# Create console app client to access the controller action ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to web development and in my ASP.Net MVC-5 project and I have made one Action which accepts a get request. I want on console desktop application to hit that action of my Controller. Below is my novice attempt. Please guide me.

In my controller I added below Action

```
 public class SecurityController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CacheClear(TestMV viewModel)
        {
            // SOME CODE
            return View();
        }
}
```

**My TestMV**

```
public class TestMV
{
    public int locationId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I go to browser and type **http://localhost:5271/Security/CacheClear/?locationId=28463** I am able to hit the breakpoint and I am able to capture the value.

**Question 1:**
 Is that it? Or do I need to do some fancy stuff for me console app to hit this Action method. Do I need to create some Web API or something. Or above code will work fine?

**Question 2:** How to access the Controller action via a desktop app.

I googled a wrote below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5271/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var resp2 = await client.GetAsync("Security/CacheClear/?locationId=28463");
            resp2.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me if I am going in the right direction. What changes I need to make in my code to acheive the result. Also, I am getting squiggly near `await client.GetAsync`. "The await method can only be used within an sync method. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

MVC controllers have a define behavior for MVC web apps. What I think you need It's to create a ASP.NET Web Api project which use Controllers that extends o inherits base class ApiController and allows you to do more than regular MVC App Controllers. Two links that would help:

Getting Started with ASP.NET Web Api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Calling a Web Api from a .NET Client

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Hope it helps!